# Warning while load xml using the DOMDocument

Tags: php

I used the following code to load the xml for further process, while load itself it display the following warning in the client server but its working fine in my local machine.

Code:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

$xmlDoc->load('http://www.domainname.com/xmlfilename');
```

> Warning: DOMDocument::load(http://www.domainname.com/xmlfilename)
>   [domdocument.load]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: I/O warning : failed
>   to load external entity "http://www.domainname.com/xmlfilename"

Comment: It seems clear that the document is inaccessible from your server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your client's server is configured with [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) set to `true`.

I'd also be checking firewall rules on the server. Perhaps it's not allowed to make HTTP requests.

Comment: if it says "connect timeout" it cannot be an `allow_url_fopen` issue.

Comment: @Gordon Yeah, wasn't sure about that one, was more of a precaution. Don't know what kind of error `DOMDocument::load()` throws if the fopen wrapper isn't enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the time until Connection Timeout before calling `load`:

```
libxml_set_streams_context(
    stream_context_create(
        array('http' => array('timeout' => 120))
    )
);
```

or

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 120);
```

See

- [`libxml_set_streams_context` — Set the streams context for the next libxml document load or write](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-set-streams-context.php)
- [HTTP Context Options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)
- [Ini Setting: `default_socket_timeout`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout)

Comment: I used the both solutions you provided, but still the problem occurs

Comment: And this issue is occurs only for the one url, for the others its working fine.

Comment: can you reach this URL via any other means? Browser? `wget`? If not, then the server is probably not available.

Comment: Yes, I can able to reach that URL through browser